# How to use 'application object' in androidTest cases? - Android

Tags: android, mockito, android-testing

I am writing test cases in **androidTest** & my code has `Pattern.EMAIL_ADDRESS`, as in unit test cases I can't have access to Android framework classes & also I am not using **Roboelectric** for the unit testing.

I am getting `NullPointerException` for application object, as in my `ResetPasswordViewModel` I am using this `application` object to get the String value form `string.xml`.
Even I have mocked `@Mock Application application`, but still it returns null. I have tried to use `InstrumentationRegistry.getTargetContext()` but still nothing's work.

Am I missing something? What could be the issue?

How to use `application` object in **androidTest** cases?
Please refer the below code:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class ResetPasswordUnitTestsInt {

ResetPasswordViewModel resetPasswordViewModel;
@Rule
public InstantTaskExecutorRule instantTaskExecutorRule = new InstantTaskExecutorRule();
@Mock
Application application;
@Mock
Patterns patterns;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    resetPasswordViewModel = new ResetPasswordViewModel(application);
}

@Test
public void a_testEmailIdFieldNegativeCase() {
    resetPasswordViewModel.userName.setValue("");
    resetPasswordViewModel.setErrorVisibilityIfBlankField();
    Assert.assertEquals(true, resetPasswordViewModel.userNameErrorVisibility.getValue());
}
}
```

[image: NulllPointerError]

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.test.newtest"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.1"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}

testOptions {
    unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
}

testOptions {
    unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
def design = "28.0.0"
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$design"
implementation "com.android.support:design:$design"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$design"

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'

implementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"
//testImplementation "android.arch.core:core-testing:1.1.1"


// reactive
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit-mock:2.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.8.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'

def daggerVer = 2.16
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVer"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVer"
compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
implementation 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'

//implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

def lifeCycle = "1.1.1"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifeCycle"
/*implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifeCycle"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifeCycle"*/
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$lifeCycle"
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:3.2.0'
annotationProcessor 
"android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$lifeCycle"

implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

implementation 'commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.3'
implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'
androidTestImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.18.3'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you missed something in androidTest configuration(maybe somewhere in gradle). You tried to use unit test practices instead of automation tests. Anyway here is an example of a mock configuration based on your error:

```
    Mockito.when(applicaiton.getResources().getString(org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt())).thenReturn("your mocked value")
```

Of course you will meet another errors in future. Just keep to configure any mock manually, is a hard way for a true JEDI

Comment: Also, I have updated my *build.gradle* file. Please have a look.

Comment: I have added Mockito.when(context.getResources().getString(org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.anyInt())).thenReturn("My Mocked text"); but now I am getting Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0 this Exception.
Let's be a true JEDI ;-)